# Relative motion with two observers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

> For four particles A, B, C, D , the velocities of one with respect to other are given as $ V_{DC}$ (Velocity of D with respect to A) is 20 m per second towards north, $ V_{BC}$ is 20 m per second towards east and 
>   $ V_{BA}$ is 20 m per second towards south. Then $ V_{DA}$ is

My take: when the observer is C the D particle is at 90 degree to B. So by corolary if B is towards south w.r.t. A then D will be towards west w.r.t A.

But I think I am not going concept wise. So is there a way to think about it conceptually?

Answer (score 1):

This time, you got the right answer using your intuitive reasoning because all the velocities are equal in magnitude. However, you will not be so lucky most of the time, in more complicated situations.

Yes, definitely, concepts can be used here.

Consider the four directions(north,south,east,west) as the ends of two dimensional co-ordinate axes:

[image]

Now, I assume you know the basics of vector arithmetic: addition,subtraction,products etc.(though we won't need any kind of products here).

I also assume you know the basic definition of relative velocity, and WHY it is so. Its is as given below:

Relative velocity of, say, A with respect to B is ***V<sub>AB</sub>*** = ***V<sub>A</sub> - V<sub>B</sub>***

You can now, therefore, use the data given in the question to frame three equations as follows ( taking **i** unit vector along east direction and **j** unit vector along north direction:

***V<sub>D</sub>*** - ***V<sub>C</sub>*** = 20 **j** 
***V<sub>B</sub>*** - ***V<sub>C</sub>*** = 20 **i** 
***V<sub>B</sub>*** - ***V<sub>A</sub>*** = -20 **j**

On manipulating these equations to obtain ***V<sub>D</sub>*** - ***V<sub>A</sub>***, the answer will indeed be 20 m/s towards west.